# how can I detect SD card insertion and usb HDD insertion from nodejs under raspbian/ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, detection, mount, sd-card, usb-drive

I want 2 things from node js:

- detect SD card insertion to the SD card reader and get the mount point (and the free space)
- detect when USB HDD is plugged into an usb port, and get the mount point (and the free space)

I'm using raspbian/ubuntu linux, and I hope there is a solution where I don't need to poll devices from an setInterval call.

I'm now using now 'usb-detection' lib, it detects when usb devices plugged, but it does not detect sd card insert.

I know there is a "drivelist" module, but it needs to constantly polling it. Is there a better way? (Couse linux knows about mounting a new thing).

Or I can ask the same question other way, how can I detect when mounting something to raspbian/ubuntu without polling "drivelist"?

*edit:*

meanwhile I have an other idea, if I watch the /media folder the system mounts the connected drives to there. So I can watch the filesystem. What do you think?

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
var baseDirToWatch='/media';

var deviceList=[];

const driveAdded = function (path)
{
  if (path!==baseDirToWatch)
  {
    deviceList.push(path);
    console.log(deviceList);
  }
}

const driveRemoved= function (path)
{
  deviceList.indexOf(path) > -1 ? deviceList.splice(deviceList.indexOf(path), 1) : false
  console.log(deviceList);
}

const watcher = chokidar.watch(baseDirToWatch, {
  persistent: true,
  depth:1
});

watcher
  .on('addDir', path => { driveAdded(path); })
  .on('unlinkDir', path => { driveRemoved(path); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [drivelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist) module.